# how do I divide large number into two smaller integers and then reassemble the large number?

Tags: division, modulo, powerpc

i have tried the below but do not seem to get the correct value in the end:
I have a number that may be larger than 32bit and hence I want to store it into two 32 bit array indices. 
I broke them up like:

```
int[0] = lgval%(2^32);
int[1] = lgval/(2^32);
```

and reassembling the 64bit value I tried like:
**CPU: PowerPC e500v2**

```
lgval= ((uint64)int[0]) | (((uint64)int[1])>>32);
```

mind shift to right since we're on big endian. For some reason I do not get the correct value at the end, why not? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "shift to right since we're on big endian" - huh? Endianness is about storage, not arithmetic. (Also, that does not look like PowerPC assembly code.)

Comment: @RaymondChen endianness = bit order, 1 in little endian is 0001 where 1 in big endian is 1000, and hence it has to be shifted in the order direction, does it not?

Comment: That's not what endianness is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` operator is xor, not power.

The way you want to do this is probably:

```
uint32_t split[2];
uint64_t lgval;

/* ... */

split[0] = lgval & 0xffffffff;
split[1] = lgval >> 32;

/* code to operate on your 32-bit array elements goes here */

lgval = ((uint64_t)split[1] << 32) | (uint64_t)(split[0]);
```

As Raymond Chen has mentioned, endianness is about storage. In this case, you only need to consider endianness if you want to access the bytes in your split-32-bit-int as a single 64-bit value. This probably isn't a good idea anyway.

Comment: "The ^ operator is xor, not power." shoot, right! That's what messed me up!... :o Please see my reply above to Raymond's comment - are you sure I don't need to switch this for big endian???

Comment: Endianness is only how those values are stored in memory. These operators are independent of endianness.